# python list duplicating instead of concatenating

Tags: python

```
class Rating():
    def __init__(self, user, item, rating):
        self.user = user
        self.item = item
        self.rating = rating

    def __str__(self):
        return str(user) + " " + str(item) + " " + str(rating)

    def __repr__(self):
        return str(user) + " " + str(item) + " " + str(rating)


data = open('data.dat').readlines()
records = ()

for i in data:
    user, item, rating = i.split()
    r = Rating(user, item, rating)
    records += (r,)
    print records
```

`data = [A, B, C]`, I'd expect `records` to have `(<Record> A, <Record> B, <Record> C)`. But instead it contains `(<Record> C, <Record> C, <Record> C)`?

Comment: `tuple`s are immutable and `list`s are not. Try `records = []` instead

Comment: @inspectorG4dget I did try it with a list, but not using a list  shouldn't affect my ability to concatenate tuples.

Comment: @inspectorG4dget He's not trying to mutate the tuple, though.

Comment: how does class `Rating` look like?

Comment: @OttoAllmendinger That's not the case.

Comment: @yedpodtrzitko Added the `Rating` class, sorry for excluding it.

Comment: Are you using `lambda` somewhere in your code?

Comment: What happens when you do `print i` after `for i in data:`?
In any case, doing tuple concatenation is inefficent. You should be using a `list` and the `list`'s `append()` method instead.

Comment: What happens if you just do `records = [Rating(*line.split()) for line in data]` ?

Comment: I just found the bug in my code. It's in the `Ratings` class. (Hint: I was printing out `records` to see what was in it.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are not using the class attributes, but the global variables you have defined by chance.

```
return str(user) + " " + str(item) + " " + str(rating)
```

Should look like

```
return str(self.user) + " " + str(self.item) + " " + str(self.rating)
```

Answer (score 4):

Your class's `__str__` is reference global names:

```
def __str__(self):
    return str(user) + " " + str(item) + " " + str(rating)
```

Which will be the last iteration of:

```
user, item, rating = i.split()
```

That needs to be fixed to be `self.user`, `self.item` etc...

Also I would change your line to be the more efficient and Pythonic:

```
records = [Rating(*line.split()) for line in data]
```

Comment: What does `*line.split()`, specifically the asterisks mean?

Comment: @user1850672 See [unpacking argument lists](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists).